# Expandable list, jumps one pixel on highlight

Tags: jquery, css

I have this list **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/epjrej64/4/)**

Im trying to figure out why, if you highlight a item in group B, it shifts down one pixle.
This does not happen on group A. Why?

Here is the JQuery

> ```
> $(".expandListHeader").click(function () {
>     $header = $(this);
>     $content = $header.next();
>     $content.find('.expandListContentRow').toggle("slow"); });
>
> $( ".expandListItem" ).click(function() {
>     $( this ).toggleClass( "highlight" ); 
> });
> ```

CSS for Highlight.

```
  .highlight{
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    border-top:1px solid #bbb;
    border-bottom:1px solid #bbb;
    background: #FFEC80;
  }
```

Comment: Yes but I want the border. It does not jump on A though

Comment: When I look at it, it jumps on both A and B. Can you have the border at all times, and just change its color?

Comment: It works in FF anyway but as Nick said `<br>` tag caused the problem

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili it's still jumping - this has nothing to do with br tag. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/epjrej64/5/)

I removed the `<br>` on line 43

```
            <div class="expandListHeader">
                <div class="Collapse"></div>
                <div class="expandListHeaderRow"><span>B</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="expandListContent">
                <div class="expandListContentRow contentCol">
                    <div class="expandListItem">Barney</div>
                    <div class="expandListItem">Ben</div>
                    <div class="expandListItem">Billy</div>
                    <div class="expandListItem">Boris</div>
                    <div class="expandListItem">Bruce</div>
                    <div class="expandListItem">Bryse</div>


                    <div class="expandListItem">Buck</div>
/*br was here*/
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Sneaky little break tag.

Comment: @mornenel look better divs are still jumping since this is unrelated to br tag.

Comment: @easwee What browser are you using? Because it isn't jumping in chrome&firefox,

Comment: @Nick I'm using chrome - it is jumping since this behaviour is related to the box-model and not to html.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are applying border to your highlighted div. Normal box-model counts content as 100% height, than adds padding to that and 1px border. Since in the begining your border is not defined your div has a smaller total height. Once you hightlight your div it will get +1px in height since the border is added to the content `height + padding`.

Either apply a transparent border to `.expandListItem` - `border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;`

```
.expandListItem {
    width: 340px;
    padding-left:10px; 
    font-size:13px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px; 
    padding-left: 20px; 
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/easwee/jkx1wu0n/1/

Comment: It's still jumping in your fiddle, click on a name that starts with 'B' and you'll see.

Comment: +1 - Real solution. You could also add `margin-top: -1px` to `.expandListItem` and prevent the double border when two adjacent items are selected.

Comment: @misterManSam true - added for the sake of complete case.